# Find difference in results between two similar queries

Tags: t-sql, duplicates

Apologies if this has been asked before. A search returned results that looked to specific for my case.

I run the following queries

### Query A

```
select c.caseid
from customer c
where left(c.workercd,1) = 'V'
and c.enddate is null
```

Query A returns 199 results.

### Query B

```
select c.caseid, p.* 
from customer c
left outer join payment p on c.CaseID = p.caseid
--inner join paymenttypelookup ptl on p.paymenttypeid = ptl.paymenttypeid
where left(c.workercd,1) = 'V'
and c.enddate is null
and (p.paymenttypeid not between 9 and 13 or p.paymenttypeid is null)
```

Query B returns 198 results.

I'm trying to find the extra record. Using this query

```
select * 
from 
    (select c.caseid
    from customer c
    where left(c.workercd,1) = 'V'
    and c.enddate is null) as temp
where temp.caseid not in
    (select c2.caseid, p.* 
    from customer c2
    left outer join payment p on c2.CaseID = p.caseid
    --inner join paymenttypelookup ptl on p.paymenttypeid = ptl.paymenttypeid
    where left(c2.workercd,1) = 'V'
    and c2.enddate is null
    and (p.paymenttypeid not between 9 and 13 or p.paymenttypeid is null))
```

Returns this error
`Only one expression can be specified in the select list when the subquery is not introduced with EXISTS.`

**How do I recover the extra record in Query A that does not return in Query B?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason for the error is that your subquery is returning too many columns... to solve it change this:

```
where temp.caseid not in (select c2.caseid, p.* from customer c2
```

to this:

```
where temp.caseid not in (select c2.caseid from customer c2
```

Another option would be to use the `except` set operator which returns the set difference.

Comment: Although this did work, I want to give others the opportunity to come up with a solution to spread some reputation.

Comment: @gh0st Sure. As long as you award the rep based on the merits of the answer and not the need of the author do as you please :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this...

```
select c.caseid
into #temp1
from customer c
where left(c.workercd,1) = 'V'
and c.enddate is null

select c.caseid, p.* 
into #temp2
from customer c
left outer join payment p on c.CaseID = p.caseid
--inner join paymenttypelookup ptl on p.paymenttypeid = ptl.paymenttypeid
where left(c.workercd,1) = 'V'
and c.enddate is null
and (p.paymenttypeid not between 9 and 13 or p.paymenttypeid is null)
```

Now you have the data in two temporary tables which you should be able to query like this to find the missing record.

```
select * from #temp1 t1 
left join #temp2 t2 on t1.caseid = t2.caseid 
where t2.caseid is null
```

Don't forget to drop your tables afterward if you need to make adjustments

```
drop table #temp1
drop table #temp2
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try this

```
SELECT
    c.*
FROM
    customer c
    LEFT JOIN payment p ON c.caseid = p.caseid
                           AND (p.paymenttypeid NOT BETWEEN 9 AND 13
                                OR p.paymenttypeid IS NULL)
WHERE
    LEFT(c.workercd,1) = 'V'
    AND c.enddate IS NULL
    AND p.caseid IS NULL
```

Answer (score 0):

You have an answer to the syntax error

You negate the left join with the where

I bet the extra has row has p.paymenttypeid between 9 and 13